# How do I print Data from table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

1) This is my order table :

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('variant_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->integer('total');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories');
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
        $table->foreign('variant_id')->references('id')->on('variants');
    });
```

2) This is my Order Blade :

```
<tbody>

        @foreach($orders as $order)
        <tr>
        <td>{{$order->variant_name}}</td>
        <td>{{$order->quantity}}</td>
        <td>{{$order->total}}/-</td>
        </tr>
        @endforeach 
    </tbody>
```

3) This is my OrderController :

```
public function index()
{
    $orders = Order::where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
    return view('orders', compact('orders', 'variants'));
}
```

Now I want to print the variant name in my blade file but only thing I can print is id's. I've tried many things but still can't get the precise answer. I know it can be done with foreign keys but how do I use these foreign keys to print variant_name or anything from variant table.

Comment: syntax error ',' unexpected return

Comment: Read and understand Laravel relationship https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Do note that every `order` made **belongs to** one `variant`. So in your `order` model create a relationship between the `order` model and `variant` model like this:

```
public function variants(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Variant::class,'variant_id','id');
}
```

Now that the relationship has been established, we can use it whenever we have an object of the `Order` class. Let's use it in our loop:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($orders as $order)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$order->variants()->first()->variant_name}}</td>
            <td>{{$order->quantity}}</td>
            <td>{{$order->total}}/-</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach 
</tbody>
```

That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You may:

**Blade**

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($orders as $order)
    <tr>
    <td>{{$order->variants->variant_name}}</td>
    <td>{{$order->quantity}}</td>
    <td>{{$order->total}}/-</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach 
</tbody>
```

**OrderController**

```
public function index(Order $order)
{
    $orders=$order->getList();
    return view('orders', compact('orders', 'variants'));
}
```

**Order model**

```
public function variants(){
   return $this->belongsTo(Variant::class, 'variant_id');
}

public function getList()
{
   return self::with('variants')->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)->get();
}
```

Comment: Nope, Didn't worked. Error : " Trying to get property of non-object ".

Comment: Call to undefined relationship [variants] on model [App\Models\Order].

Comment: Thanks generous person, it worked this time. <3 + PEACE